# Regular expression to match everything but to leave some specified matches

Tags: regex

I have got a string like the following:

```
(GDRO WHERE PERIOD MONTH = 0 AND PERIOD QUARTER = 12) WHERE NDRO() AND KST
```

I have written the following regular expression that leaves out the numbers, symbols and functions and matches only the words.

```
/(?![A-Za-z]+\(\))([A-Za-z_](?:\d*))+/g
```

If applied to above string, result is

```
GDRO, WHERE, PERIOD, MONTH, AND, PERIOD, QUARTER, WHERE, AND, KST
```

What I also want is to make my regex leave out the specific words i.e.

```
(WHERE|PERIOD|MONTH|AND|WHERE)
```

Is there any way that I can specify this in my regular expression to leave out these given words and match every other word i.e. to get the following result?

```
GDRO, KST
```

Comment: What should happen to `QUARTER`?

Comment: It should also be ignored. Forgot to put it in the ignore list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b(?!(?:WHERE|PERIOD|MONTH|AND|WHERE)\b)(?![A-Za-z]+\(\))([A-Za-z_](?:\d*))+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/1

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, just update your negative lookahead by adding `WHERE`, `PERIOD`, `MONTH`, `AND` and `WHERE`. The regex:

```
/(?:(?![A-Za-z]+\(\)|WHERE|PERIOD|MONTH|AND|WHERE))(\b(?:[A-Za-z_](?:\d*))+\b)/g
```

Test case matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `GDRO`
MATCH 2
1.  [39-46] `QUARTER`
MATCH 3
1.  [70-73] `KST`
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/rI8jM6/2)

Comment: Wasn't me however +1ed to compensate that. Thanks for your answer :-)